# Cropped PDF still contains the original text

Tags: python, pdf, printing, pypdf, os.system

I have written a program that crops out a PDF using PyPDF2 and exports it as a new version.

e.g. I crop 123.pdf and it outputs 123 - NEW .pdf

However when using the printing function, it does not print the cropped PDF, but the original one. Even though I have specified to crop the new one.

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

order_number = entry1.get()
final = order_number.upper()
edit = PdfReader(f"{pathfile}{order_number} - Shipping Label.pdf")
output = PdfWriter()

page = edit.pages[0]
page.cropbox.upper_left = (63.389830508474574, 643.7972508591065)
page.cropbox.lower_right = (561.8644067796611, 483.2096219931271)
page.rotate(90)
output.add_page(page)

page = edit.pages[1]
page.cropbox.upper_left = (32.45454545454545, 545.4601542416452)
page.cropbox.lower_right = (556.7757575757576, 238.09768637532136)
page.rotate(90)
output.add_page(page)

with open(f"{pathfile}{final}.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    output.write(fp)
os.system(f"lpr -P Munbyn_Printer_1 {pathfile}{final}.pdf")
```

As you can see, I want to print the {final}.pdf but it prints out the original.

Comment: When you investigate the resulting PDF, does it look as expected?

Comment: @MartinThoma Yes, the whole script was working perfectly until I decided to add the print line, then it was printing the original version

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is no print in the script above

Comment: os.system(f"lpr -P Munbyn_Printer_1 {pathfile}{final}.pdf")

I am trying to physically print the cropped PDF, but it keeps printing the uncropped PDF
@MartinThoma

Comment: The issue could be one of the boxes (trimbox, artbox, mediabox, bleed box... I think there was one more). Try to set all of them to the same value. Check if it looks right on screen. Then print it

Comment: Hi, tried to add every single box in, still won't work, seems to be printing from original still

Answer (score 0):

PDF has several boxes (mediabox, cropbox, trimbox, artbox, bleedbox). Those define "views" on the underlying document.

You changed the view. That does not affect at all the contained text. It just affects what is shown when you open it with a viewer (or when you attempt to print it).

As many text extraction tools ignore the boxes, the text is still there.